# ASP.NET Hosting multiple website under same folder with same domain

Tags: asp.net, web-config, bin

I'm wondering how to host multiple websites under same folder. example:

```
www.mydomain.com/apps/app1
www.mydomain.com/apps/app2
www.mydomain.com/apps/app3
```

each of them is different app with separated web.config

my concern now is that my apps now cannot read dll files inside their own bin folder.

Is there any solution for that?

Thanks

Comment: How do you have your physical file structure laid out?  Are app1, app2, and app3 completely different directories?

Comment: Why not you make a test and try to see if works ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this within IIS. Just start up the IIS Manager and navigate to the folder (such as 'app3' in the Connections pane on the left). Right-click the folder and select Convert to Application. This will set the folder as the root for a separate ASP.NET web application.

Comment: thnx for your reply. But, the site cannot load any precompiled dlls.

Comment: what precompiled dlls can't the site load? The main site dll? what errors are you getting? I think you need to provide a bit more detail in your question regarding your current configuration and what you are trying to achieve.